# MySQL select only new records

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How to write a MySQL query to achieve this task?

**Table:** writers

```
w_id    w_name
---------------
  1     Michael
  2     Samantha
  3     John
---------------
```

**Table:** articles

```
a_id   w_id   timestamp   a_name
----------------------------------------
  1      1    0000000001  PHP programming
  2      3    0000000003  Other programming languages
  3      3    0000000005  Another article
  4      2    0000000015  Web design
  5      1    0000000020  MySQL
----------------------------------------
```

Need to SELECT only those writers who published their first article not earlier than **0000000005**.
 *(only writers who published at least one article can be selected)*

In this example the result would be:

```
  2     Samantha
```

SQL code can be tested here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a308

Comment: Why would not `1    Michael` be included in the result? As from what I can see, Michael wrote an article with timestamp 0000000020.

Comment: Yes, but his first article was on 0000000001, which is earlier than 0000000005. So he should not be included in the result list.

Answer (score 3):

Untested, but close:

```
SELECT w_id, MIN(timestamp) as min_time
from writers w
JOIN articles a on w.w_id = a.w_id
GROUP BY 1
HAVING min_time > 5
```

Comment: "Off by 1. Story of my life!" I don't get it.

Comment: Well, @pilcrow pointed out that I had used ">" instead of ">=", which would make the answer "of fby one".  Philosophically, I've found that you can also be "off by one" in life - early/late, happy/sad, etc.  Oh, and funny/not :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach, using an inline view (or "derived table" as MySQL calls it) to get the earliest timestamp for each writer:

```
SELECT w.w_id
     , w.w_name
   --  , e.earliest_timestamp
  FROM writers w
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT a.w_id
              , MIN(a.timestamp) AS earliest_timestamp
           FROM articles a
          GROUP BY a.w_id
       ) e
    ON e.w_id = w.w_id
 WHERE e.earliest_timestamp >= '0000000005'
 ORDER BY w.w_id
```

This may not be the most efficient approach, but you can run just the query in the inline view (aliased as e) to see what it returns. We can then reference the result set from that query like we do a table (with some restrictions.)

(Other approaches can make better use of suitable indexes.)

I'm unclear on the datatype of `earliest_timestamp` column. The SQL above assumes it's character datatype.  If it's integer rather than character, the WHERE clause could look like this:

```
 WHERE e.earliest_timestamp >= 5
```